# Pseudo Infinite Loop (Optimally Deleting 'missing data' from a matrix)

Tags: java, combinatorics

When I use a random matrix (class Determine), my program runs successfully in 1700 miliseconds. However, when I create a matrix by reading a file through a buffered reader (class Construct) my program experiences a logic error and enters and infinite loop.

Again, it works for a random matrix, but does not work for a 'real' matrix of the same size. I've checked my work and cannot find an error in my reading of the file. Does anyone know what may be causing this logic error? I will append my code with comments if it helps!

---

Update: OK the problem was from my own silly oversight (see my answer below). This did not occur with random data due to my 'haveIt' method and the probability of getting missing data. As such, my code has been updated to reflect this logic error and I will be happy to explain in detail how this code works if anyone  asks:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;


class ValMax {
    public static int valMax;
}

class Construct {
    private static int colEnd;
    private static int colStart;
    private static int[] colSkip;

    public static List<List<Integer>> rFile(String[] args){     
        if (args.length != 4) {
            System.out.println("Format: FileName colStart colEnd colSkipped");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            List<List<Integer>> matrix = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

            Construct.colEnd = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
            Construct.colStart = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);     
            String[] colSkipped = args[3].split(",");
            Construct.colSkip = new int[colSkipped.length];
            for (int x = 0; x < colSkipped.length; x++) {
                Construct.colSkip[x] = Integer.parseInt(colSkipped[x]);
            }

            String line;
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(args[0])));

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] tokens = line.split(",");
                List<Integer> rows = new ArrayList<Integer>(colEnd - colStart + 1 - colSkip.length);

                for (int x = 1; x <= tokens.length; x++) {
                    if (x >= colStart && x <= colEnd && contains(x, colSkip) == false) {        
                        try {
                            Double.parseDouble(tokens[x - 1]);
                        } catch (NumberFormatException e3) {
                            break;
                        }

                        if (tokens[x - 1].equals("-999")) { //
                            rows.add(2);
                        } else {
                            rows.add(1);
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (rows.size() == colEnd - colStart + 1 - colSkip.length) {
                    matrix.add(rows);
                }
            }

            System.out.println(matrix.size() + "\t" + matrix.get(0).size());
            return matrix;

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            System.out.println("IOEXCEPTION!!");
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e2) {
            System.out.println("NumberFormatException!!");
            System.exit(0);
        } finally {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e5) {
                e5.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static boolean contains(int a, int[] colSkip) {
        boolean bluejay = false;
        for (int skip : colSkip) {
            if (a == skip) {
                bluejay = true;
            }
        }

        return bluejay;
    }
}

class Determine {
    private static Integer gen(int a, int b, Random r) {
        Integer rand = r.nextInt(a) + b;

        return rand;
    }

    public static List<List<Integer>> rando() {
        Random r = new Random();
        int k = gen(1, 24, r), l = gen(1, 33, r); //userinput

        List<List<Integer>> matrix = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(k);           
        for (int x = 1; x <= k; x++) {
            List<Integer> row = new ArrayList<Integer>(l);
            for (int y = 1; y <= l; y++) {
                double bias = Math.random();
                if (bias > 0.7) {
                    row.add(2);
                } else {
                    row.add(1);
                }
            }

            matrix.add(row);
        }

        return matrix;
    }
}

class Search {
    public static void finalize(List<List<Integer>> matTan, boolean gumDrop, int minimum) {
        final int A = matTan.size();
        final int B = matTan.get(0).size();
        boolean judge = true;

        if (minimum > A && gumDrop == false || minimum > B && gumDrop == true) {
            System.out.print("\nMinimum too high\n\n");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        ValMax.valMax = 1;  //userinput
        int[] rows  = new int[2 + A + B];
        List<int[]> combination = new ArrayList<int[]>(100);            

        int threads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);

        List<List<int[]>> ranTime = new ArrayList<List<int[]>>(2 * threads);            
        for (int x = 0; x < 2 * threads; x++) {
            List<int[]> jobs = new ArrayList<int[]>(90);
            ranTime.add(jobs);
        }

        if (gumDrop == false) {
            for (int x = 1; x <= minimum; x++) {
                rows[x] = 1;
            }
        } else {
            rows[1] = 1;
        }
        rows[A + 1] = 999;

        int y = 0, z = 0;
        System.out.println(threads);
        while (rows[A + 1] == 999) {                
            y++;
            int[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(rows, rows.length);


            if (y == 91) {
                z++;
                y = 1;
                if (z < 2* threads) {
                    ranTime.get(z).clear();
                }
            }

            if (z == 2 * threads) {
                processInputs(ranTime, combination, matTan, minimum, gumDrop, service);
                z = 0;
                ranTime.get(0).clear();
                ranTime.get(0).add(copy);
            } else {
                ranTime.get(z).add(copy);
            }

            nextComb(A, rows);
        }

        if (ranTime.get(0).size() > 0) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 2 * threads; x++) {
                if (judge == false) {
                    ranTime.remove(x);
                    threads--;
                    x--;
                }

                if (ranTime.get(x).size() != 90 && judge == true) {
                    judge = false;                      
                }
            }

            processInputs(ranTime, combination, matTan, minimum, gumDrop, service);
        }

        service.shutdown();

        try {
            service.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e6) {
            System.out.print("Termination Error!");
        }

        developed(matTan, combination, gumDrop);
    }

    private static void processInputs(List<List<int[]>> ranTime, List<int[]> combination, List<List<Integer>> matTan, int minimum, boolean gumDrop, ExecutorService service) {
        Collection<StringTask> collection = new ArrayList<StringTask>(ranTime.size());      
        for (List<int[]> jobs : ranTime) {
            StringTask analysis = new StringTask(jobs, combination, matTan, minimum, gumDrop);
            collection.add(analysis);
        }

        try {
            List<Future<Integer>> futures = service.invokeAll(collection);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void developed(List<List<Integer>> matTan, List<int[]> combination, boolean gumDrop) {
        System.out.print("\n\n\n");
        for (int[] e : combination) {
            if (e[0] == ValMax.valMax) { // == ValMax.valMax
                Optimize10.prin(e);
                List<List<Integer>> complete = Multi.reduct1(e, matTan);
                if (gumDrop == true) {
                    System.out.println("Solution Matrix, transposed [above data works on column]"); 
                    Optimize10.prin(Multi.transpose(complete)); //The solution matrix, reorientated
                } else {                
                    System.out.println("Solution Matrix");  
                    Optimize10.prin(complete); //The solution matrix, reorientated
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void nextComb(int bounds, int[] rows) {
        int kappas = findMax(rows);
        if (rows[bounds] == 0) {
            rows[kappas + 1] = 1;
            rows[kappas] = 0;
        } else {
            int y = 1;
            int x = bounds;
            while (rows[x] == 1) {
                rows[x] = 0;
                y++;
                x--;                        
            }
            kappas = findMax(rows);
            if (kappas != -1) {
                rows[kappas] = 0;
            }
            int z = kappas + 1;
            while (y > 0) {
                rows[z] = 1;
                z++;
                y--;
            }
        }
    }

    private static int findMax(int[] rows) {
        int y = 0;
        for (int x = rows.length - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
            if (rows[x] == 1) {
                return x;
            }
        }

        return y;
    }
}

class StringTask implements Callable<Integer> {
    private List<List<Integer>> matTan;
    private List<int[]> combination;
    private List<int[]> jobs;
    private boolean gumDrop;
    private int minimum;

    StringTask(List<int[]> a, List<int[]> b, List<List<Integer>> c, int d, boolean e) {
        this.combination = b;
        this.minimum = d;
        this.gumDrop = e;
        this.matTan = c;
        this.jobs = a;
    }

    public Integer call() {
        for (int[] e : jobs) {
            int temp = Multi.reduct2(e, matTan, minimum, gumDrop);
            if (temp > ValMax.valMax) { //ValMax.valMax //userinput
                ValMax.valMax = e[0]; //userinput
                combination.add(e);
                System.out.print(ValMax.valMax + " ");
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}

class Multi {
    public static int[] inverse;

    public static void halveIt(int[] col, List<List<Integer>> matCop) {
        int size = matCop.size(), a = 0;
        inverse = new int[size];
        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < matCop.get(0).size(); y++) {
                if (col[y] == 1 && matCop.get(x).get(y) == 2) {
                    inverse[x + a] = 1;
                    matCop.remove(x);
                    size--;
                    x--;
                    a++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static List<List<Integer>> reduct1(int[] row, List<List<Integer>> matCan) {
        List<List<Integer>> matTan = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(matCan);

        int with = matTan.size(), high = inverse.length, a = 0;
        final int B = matCan.get(0).size() - 1;
        final int A = matCan.size();

        for (int x = 0; x < A; x++) {
            List<Integer> value = new ArrayList<Integer>(matCan.get(x));
            matTan.set(x, value);
        }

        int y = 0, size = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < high; x++) {                        
            if (x < with) {
                if (row[x + a + 1] > 0) {
                    size = matTan.get(0).size();
                    for (y = 0; y < size; y++) {
                        if (matTan.get(x).get(y) == 2) {
                            for (int z = 0; z < with ; z++) {                                                                                   
                                matTan.get(z).remove(y);
                            }                               
                            size--;
                            y--;
                        }
                    }

                } else {
                    matTan.remove(x);
                    with--;
                    high--;
                    x--;
                    a++;
                }
            }
        }

        return matTan;
    }

    public static int reduct2(int[] row, List<List<Integer>> matCan, int minimum, boolean gumDrop) {
        int b = 0, c = 0, d = 0, e = 0, g = 0, high = inverse.length;
        final int B = matCan.get(0).size() - 1;
        final int A = matCan.size();
        for (int x = 0; x < high; x++) {                            
            if (x < A) {
                if (row[x + 1] > 0) {
                    b++;
                    for (int y = 0; y < B + 1; y++) {                           
                        if (matCan.get(x).get(y) == 2 && row[2 + A + y] == 0) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                            row[2 + A + y] = 1; // 1s mean that a column was deleted, 0 is kept.                            
                            d -= e;                             
                        } else if (row[2 + A + y] == 0) {
                            d++;
                        }
                    }
                    e++;
                }
            }

            if (inverse[x] == 0 && x < high || gumDrop == true && x < high) {
                if (row[x - c + 1] == 1) {
                    row[x - c + 1] = 1 + c + g;
                    g++;
                } else {
                    g++;
                }
            } else {
                c++;
            }
        }

        if (d / b < minimum && gumDrop == true) {
            row[0] = 0;
            d = 0;
        } else {
            row[0] = d;
        }

        return d;
    }

    public static List<List<Integer>> transpose(List<List<Integer>> matTan) {
        int d = matTan.get(0).size();

        List<List<Integer>> matFlip = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(d);
        for (int y = 0; y < d; y++) {
            List<Integer> row = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for (int x = 0; x < matTan.size(); x++) {
                row.add(matTan.get(x).get(y));
            }
            matFlip.add(row);
        }

        return matFlip;
    }
}
```

// ########## Main Method Start ##########

```
public class Optimize10 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double startTime = System.nanoTime() / 1000000;
        List<List<Integer>> matrix = Determine.rando();

    //  List<List<Integer>> matrix = Construct.rFile(args);
        List<List<Integer>> matTan = contract(new int[matrix.get(0).size()], matrix);
        int a = matTan.size(), b = matTan.get(0).size();

        System.out.println(a + "\t" + b);

        boolean gumDrop = false;
        int minimum = 40; //userinput

        BigInteger aNew = new BigInteger("2");
        BigInteger bNew = new BigInteger("2");                      
        aNew = aNew.pow(a);
        bNew = bNew.pow(b);

        for (int x = 1; x < minimum; x++) {
            aNew = aNew.subtract(binomial(a, x));           
        }

        if (aNew.compareTo(bNew) > 0) {
            gumDrop = true;
            matTan = Multi.transpose(matTan);
        }

        System.out.println(gumDrop);
        prin(matrix);
        prin(matTan);

        Search.finalize(matTan, gumDrop, minimum);
        double endTime = System.nanoTime() / 1000000;
        double duration = (endTime - startTime);
        System.out.println(duration);   
    }

// ########## MAIN METHOD END ############      

    private static BigInteger binomial(final int N, final int K) {
        BigInteger ret = BigInteger.ONE;
        for (int k = 0; k < K; k++) {
            ret = ret.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(N-k)).divide(BigInteger.valueOf(k+1));
        }

        return ret;
    }

    private static List<List<Integer>> contract(int[] col, List<List<Integer>> matrix) {
        List<List<Integer>> matCop = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(matrix);
        col[0] = 1; //userinput 1 means don't delete!
        col[1] = 1; //userinput
        col[2] = 1;
        col[12] = 1;
        col[14] = 1;
        col[22] = 1;
        col[28] = 1;
        col[29] = 1;
        Multi.halveIt(col, matCop);

        return matCop;
    }

    public static void prin(List<List<Integer>> matrix) {
        for (int x = 0; x < matrix.size(); x ++) {
            System.out.print("[" + matrix.get(x).get(0));
            for (int y = 1; y < matrix.get(0).size(); y++) {
                System.out.print(" " + matrix.get(x).get(y));
            }
            System.out.print("]\n");
        }   
        System.out.print("\n\n");
    }

    public static void prin(int[] a) {
        System.out.print("[" + a[0]);       
        for (int x = 1; x < a.length; x ++) {
            System.out.print(" " + a[x]);
        }
        System.out.print("]\n\n");  
    }

    public static void prin(String[] a) {
        System.out.print("[" + a[0]);       
        for (int x = 1; x < a.length; x ++) {
            System.out.print(" " + a[x]);
        }
        System.out.print("]\n\n");  
    }

    public static void prin2(List<Integer> a) {
        System.out.print("[" + a.get(0));       
        for (int x = 1; x < a.size(); x ++) {
            System.out.print(" " + a.get(x));
        }
        System.out.print("]\n\n");  
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I found the source. Going to see if i can fix it. I need to give these problems more thought before submitting them. Sorry.

Comment: The source is probably that my minimum number of rows at line 7 of my main method was too large at 40, even though my parsed matrix could handle it. I'm running the code with minimum = 1 right now, but it''ll take 2 hours to finish before I know this is actually the problem. I wonder why minimum 40 is causing an infinite loop?

Comment: I haven't tried to understand your whole code, but there's something that calls to mind: you run some asynchronous code by using Callable and an ExecutorService, which means that you'll have several tasks executed in parallel. But you never call awaitTermination, which means that your program may end before everything is executed. It may result in unexpected behaviours, like the one you're pointing out.

Comment: Glad to hear that you've solved your problem, but don't put "solved" in the title.  Since you've got an answer, go ahead and mark it as accepted. I understand that the system is delaying that, but wait it out - accepting answers is the Stack Exchange way of declaring a problem "solved".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so there actually was no infinite loop in this code whatsoever. The problem was with line 466 of my code; specifically, I was basing whether I analyzed the original matrix or its transpose on the number of rows after truncation on the original matrix and subtracting the minimum. This is wrong because, for example,

sum_{i = 40)^{54}(54 choose i) >> 2^32.

My program was taking forever because it was told to traverse through over a trillion combinations instead of 'just' a few billion. Granted it can do 10 billion in about 2 hours, and I can save more time by inverting a few nested for loops (another time).

I Guess it's time to learn profiling to see where my code slows down.